# How outbound SMTP gets encrypted by the client?

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, email-server

When my SMTP server sends an email to another server and is supposed to use TLS, the receiver will offer his destination domain certificate (I assume). Which certificate does my server use to encrypt the connection. Does it in theory even need its own to make the connection secure? (ignoring DKIM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without DKIM: In most cases there isn't a client cert required or used, as in this variant, the encryption is only about privacy, not authenticity (at least for the sender), just like when you connect to a `https` server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Protocol_details.